# Stop notifications from a deleted app

Tags: ipod-touch, applications, ipod, notifications

I got the app Baby Story for my iPod Touch a while ago, and then decided I didn't like it and deleted it. Part of the reason I got rid of it was because it would pop up random messages with things like, "Your baby is hungary!" The app appears to be completely deleted, and I can't find any reference to it on the iPod anywhere, but I'll still get random notifications with things like, "Your baby is sick." Is there a way, short of reformatting the iPod, to stop these messages?

Answer (score 2):

Removing an app should disable all of the Push Notifications. Try rebooting your iPod, and making sure that iTunes did not re-install it.

Also, you can try disabling all Notifications, then -re-enabling them.

Maybe post a screenshot of the message. You may have another app installed (mBox for example) that displays messages from apps that send emails as well. *(of course this is just a far fetched scenario).*

Answer (score 1):

Try going into the "notifications" settings in your iPod's settings to see if u can the app listed there. If so then just turn off it's notification privileges.

Comment: I looked in there, but I didn't see the app. I thought about reinstalling the app and then trying to turn off the notifications, but I'm afraid I'll just get stuck with twice as many.

Comment: Reinstalling would probably be the way to go. Then you can block the application all together and remove it without a problem. If this doubles the amount of notifications, you should report it as a bug to Apple.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Apparently, what I needed to do was ask about it here. Since I posted about it I don't think I've had any notifications from the application.

Comment: haha victory! :D